# Update button spin not being updated by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following JQuery, Ajax calls are made upon setinterval to update screen values and after a timeout the interval is cleared and updates stop. This part works.
However, upon user clicking the update button a set number of Ajax updates are to be made (10). At the beginning the spinner is set to spin by adding the class and after all the updates the spinner class is removed to make the spinner stop. However, the spinner never even starts - all other screen updates work as desired. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      // set an interval. The callback gets executed every interval
      var setInterval1_ID = setInterval(triggerAjax, 10000); // 10 sec updates
      var timeout1_ID = setTimeout(stopSetInterval1, 100000); // this is 100 seconds for 10 updates

      $(document).on("click", "#refresh-button", function() {
        $("#refresh-button").addClass("fa-spin");
        var count = 0;
        while (count <= 9) {
          count = count + 1;
          triggerAjax();
        }
        $("#refresh-button").removeClass("fa-spin");
      });

      function stopSetInterval1() {
        // clear the interval trigger explicitly
        clearInterval(setInterval1_ID);

        // stop spinning of update wheel
        $("#refresh-button").removeClass("fa-spin");
        // also clear the timeout
        clearTimeout(timeout1_ID);
      }

      function triggerAjax() {
        $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, { //POST request
            _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce, //nonce extracted and sent
            action: "get_studer_readings" // hook added for action wp_ajax_get_studer_readings in php file
          },
          function(data) { // data is JSON data sent back by server in response, wp_send_json($somevariable)
            // update the page with new readings. Lets just log the value sto see if we are getting good data
            // console.log('data: ', data);
            // console.log('battery html', $('#power-battery').html());

            //Change Inverter output power value using Ajax delivered object data
            $('#power-load').html(data.pout_inverter_ac_kw + ' kW');

            // change the arrow class for Inverter Pout to Home using Ajax update
            $('#power-arrow-load').removeClass().addClass(data.inverter_pout_arrow_class);

            // Solar Power related values Ajax update
            //Change Solar output power value using Ajax delivered object data
            $('#power-solar').html(Math.round(data.psolar_kw, 2) + ' kW<br>' + '<font color="#D0D0D0">' +
              data.solar_pv_adc + 'A');
            // todo need to add the SOlar-PB current at battery interface
            // update the arrow based on ajax
            $('#power-arrow-solar').removeClass().addClass(data.solar_arrow_class);

            // Change the Battery values based on Ajax update
            $('#power-arrow-battery').removeClass().addClass(data.battery_charge_arrow_class);
            //Change Inverter output power value using Ajax delivered object data
            $('#power-battery').html(data.pbattery_kw + ' kW<br>' + '<font color="#D0D0D0">' +
              data.battery_voltage_vdc + 'V<br>' +
              data.battery_charge_adc + 'A');

            //Change Grid AC in power and arrow calss based on Ajax updates
            //Change Inverter output power value using Ajax delivered object data
            $('#ppower-grid-genset').html(data.grid_pin_ac_kw + ' kW<br>' + '<font color="#D0D0D0">' +
              data.grid_input_vac + 'V<br>' +
              data.grid_input_aac + 'A');
            // change the arrow class for Inverter Pout to Home using Ajax update
            $('#power-arrow-grid-genset').removeClass().addClass(data.grid_input_arrow_class);
          });
      }
});
```

Comment: What's the point of calling the Ajax function 10 times in a row on a single button click? You're calling `triggerAjax();` in a `while` loop 10 times, and there is nothing that waits for any of those requests to return. There is no interval. All 10 requests go out at the same moment, and you're probably hitting your brower's concurrent XHR request limit by doing that.

Comment: ...but even if that part was working, why do 10 updates in a row and then stop? From an UI semantics point of view, would it not make sense to either have *"one button click = one update"* or *"button acts as continuous auto-refresh start/stop"*? The "just 10 updates" behavior seems awfully arbitrary.

Comment: To clarify, the intent is to not continuously update but in bursts based on demand. Values are changing asynchronously. The Ajax makes API calls on server side to get the asynchronous values to update the screen. I tried a setInterval and a timeout to gate it but it only worked the 1st time and didn't work on demand. The 10 number is arbitrary but it does reflect changing values fetched by Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.post` is Asynchronous so it will add or remove the class within millisecond, you can make it synchronous but it not recommended because it will make your browser freeze/unresponsive, put `$("#refresh-button").removeClass("fa-spin");` in post callback

```
var count = 0; // <== make the variable global
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      .......
      // update the following
      $(document).on("click", "#refresh-button", function() {
        $("#refresh-button").addClass("fa-spin");
        count = 0;
        var thisCount = 0
        while (thisCount <= 9) {
          thisCount++;
          triggerAjax();
        }
      });

      function triggerAjax() {
        $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, { //POST request
          .......
          function(data) {
            ...........
            $('#power-arrow-grid-genset').removeClass().addClass(data.grid_input_arrow_class);
            // add this block
            count++; // <== update count
            if(count == 9){
                $("#refresh-button").removeClass("fa-spin"); // <== remove it here
            }
            // end block
          });
      }
});
```

the above code will make you post run in parallel to to serialize

```
 $(document).on("click", "#refresh-button", function() {
    $("#refresh-button").addClass("fa-spin");
    count = 0;
    triggerAjax();
  });

function triggerAjax() {
$.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, { //POST request
  .......
  function(data) {
    ...........
    $('#power-arrow-grid-genset').removeClass().addClass(data.grid_input_arrow_class);
    // add this block
    count++;
    if(count == 9){
        $("#refresh-button").removeClass("fa-spin");
    }
    else{
        triggerAjax();
    }
    // end block
  });
}
```

Comment: That did the trick :-) I can fine tune delays and the count to suit the required display rate of the asynchronous data from the API calls in the Ajax. Thanks for the help.